# Xcode doesn't recognize iPhone "Launch Images"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using XCode 4.5. I noticed XCode fails to detect the "**Launch Images**" ONLY for iPhone and iPhone (3.5-inch), but for Retina (4 inch) and iPad they are okay.

My files list:

```
Default-568h@2x.png (OK)
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png (OK)
Default-Portrait~ipad.png (OK)
Default.png (Not shown in summary page)
Default@2x.png (Not shown in summary page)
```

Any reason or should I need a better name for these files?

Comment: Names look ok, but did you perhaps mixed the case in the info.plist, because on a device `default.png` is not equal to `Default.png`

Comment: @rckoenes, I havn't defined the `Default*` in info.plist, e.g. `cat info.plist | grep -i default` return nonthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try for iPhone:

- Default-iphone.png
- Default@2x-iphone.png